# In registration form adding date dialogbox how can apply validation in system date in dialog ends with system date in android

Tags: android

i am implementing registration form adding date field  then click icon to display date dialog window  then limit date validation in system date below date only how can implement the validation

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
     {

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
switch (id) {
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
return new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,  cyear, cmonth, cday);
        }
    return null;
    }
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
 {
String date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"+String.valueOf(year);
EditText birthday=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBirthday);
    birthday.setText(date_selected);
    }
};
public void onClick(View v) 
{
if(v == b1)
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }
}

**

showing in system date in below dates only how can implemented
```

some solution  in running year to below years are display  not incrementing above years this condition are appliying validations how can implemented ?

Comment: is it that you want to validate birthday entered should not be greater than the system date?

Comment: year only current year to below years only only for year validation how can implemented
not date and month   only year